# Android app keeps crashing on button click

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-emulator, crash

I have looked at other Qs and answers but cannot find anything wrong with my code?
I must be doing something wrong, so if anyone can help me out, it would be much appreciated.
I have checked the 1st and 2nd pages and the manifest.

```
package com.example.fmf;

import com.example.fmf.Search;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   goMenu();
            }

        });
    }


    public void goMenu()
    {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Search.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
    } 


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Page 2

```
package com.example.fmf;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

public class Search extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-       vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 public final String ID_CITY = extras.getString("CITY_TH");

//retrieve list view value selected and store in variable restaurant
//Not sure how to do this...



}
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Search"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Info"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".Search" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Search" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Sorry for the delay the log cat (Not sure how to post all of it)

```
11-27 15:40:05.118: D/AndroidRuntime(771): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-27 15:40:05.128: D/AndroidRuntime(771): CheckJNI is ON
11-27 15:40:05.158: D/dalvikvm(771): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-27 15:40:05.168: D/dalvikvm(771): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-27 15:40:05.198: D/dalvikvm(771): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-27 15:40:05.198: D/dalvikvm(771): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-27 15:40:05.278: E/cutils-trace(771): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-27 15:40:05.868: D/AlertService(549): Beginning updateAlertNotification
11-27 15:40:05.898: D/AndroidRuntime(771): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-27 15:40:05.918: D/dalvikvm(771): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 163 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-27 15:40:05.948: I/ActivityManager(286): Force stopping package com.example.fmf appid=10048 user=-1
11-27 15:40:05.959: I/ActivityManager(286): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.fmf/.MainActivity} from pid 771
11-27 15:40:06.328: I/WindowManager(286): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{419849f0 ActivityRecord{41984880 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}} appWin=Window{419646b0 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} drawState=4
11-27 15:40:06.328: W/WindowManager(286): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (480x800) to layer 21000
11-27 15:40:06.338: D/AndroidRuntime(771): Shutting down VM
11-27 15:40:06.348: D/dalvikvm(771): GC_CONCURRENT freed 92K, 16% free 513K/608K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 11ms
11-27 15:40:06.358: D/AlertService(549): No fired or scheduled alerts
11-27 15:40:06.388: W/dalvikvm(783): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 0 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-27 15:40:06.388: W/dalvikvm(783): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 1 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
```

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: Have looked up the trace file error but found it was usually caused with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in the wrong place but I'm pretty sure it's in the right place for me?

Comment: Please post your app's exception stacktrace from logcat, not just some random logcat rows.

Answer (score 2):

Without a stacktrace it can be hard to tell. From what I can see you have two possible culprites.

**First**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
public final String ID_CITY = extras.getString("CITY_TH");
```

In your Search class you are trying to get data from bundle. But in your MainActivity.goMenu()  you are not passing in a bundle. This can cause a `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION`

**Second**

```
setupActionBar();
```

Please try commenting that out in your Search.class and see what the results are. I can't see what your theme is from the manifest. So you may not even have an Action bar which can cause a crash. So if commenting out the line above works, add the following to your manifest:

Change:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

To:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Beat me to it. Definitely worth commenting out those two lines to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Also, once those are working, they should be moved inside of a method like `onCreate()`

Comment: I've been trying to change the manifest to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo"` yet i keep getting an error saying no resource found? @Brianjs

Comment: No the app still crashes when i press the button on the emulator. With `setupActionBar();` commented out and the `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
public final String ID_CITY = extras.getString("CITY_TH");` removed?  @Brianjs thanks for your help

Comment: Have you commented out the setupActionBar() and the two Bundle lines?

Comment: Yes and still crashes?! @Brianjs

Comment: You can try the suggestion above. Otherwise we will definitely need the stack trace (The error from logcat).

Comment: Show us LogCat please. It is more safety than dreaming your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
               goMenu();
        }

    });
}


public void goMenu()
{
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Search.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Just try to replace this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Search.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks but I originally had what you're suggesting and changed it to the current one to try and fix the problem so I don't think that's it (although yours is probably better). @user2675569